# How to dump ASP.NET Request headers to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to email myself a quick dump of a GET request's headers for debugging. I used to be able to do this in classic ASP simply with the Request object, but `Request.ToString()` doesn't work. And the following code returned an empty string:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    string requestHeaders = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // ...
    // send requestHeaders here
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Have a look at the [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx) property in the Request object.

**C#**

```
string headers = Request.Headers.ToString();
```

Or, if you want it formatted in some other way:

```
string headers = String.Empty;
foreach (var key in Request.Headers.AllKeys)
  headers += key + "=" + Request.Headers[key] + Environment.NewLine;
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Dim headers = Request.Headers.ToString()
```

Or:

```
Dim headers As String = String.Empty
For Each key In Request.Headers.AllKeys
  headers &= key & "=" & Request.Headers(key) & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: +1 Just add a line to email it and I think this is the full answer (the question was tagged C# so I don't think the VB.Net version is essential).

Comment: First KeyValuePair snippet caused runtime cast error so I'm using foreach (string key in Request.Headers) header += key + " = " + Request.Headers[key] + Environment.NewLine;

Comment: You may join all data using string.Join method:
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Request.Headers.AllKeys.Select(key=>string.Format("Key:{0}, Value:{1}", key, Request.Headers[key])));

This method is faster then your because string.Join is more effective to join several objects

Comment: For AspNetCore, headers are wrapped because of Kestrel and the key is prefixed with 'Header', so you would need to iterate the header dictionary and then dump the key-value-pairs, probably removing the word 'Header'.

Comment: This also works for the Form object on a request just fyi

Comment: Instead of AllKeys, I would iterate the collection directly, getting both key and the corresponding values.

Comment: this doesn't return custom headers

Comment: @Toolkit: Is that so? Can you give an example?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 3.1 `Request.Headers.ToString()` returns data type name `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders` and `Request.Headers` has no `AllKeys` member.

Answer (score 30):

You could turn on tracing on the page to see headers, cookies, form variables, querystring etc painlessly:

Top line of the aspx starting:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true"
```

Comment: Trace not available for this configuration: `<deployment retail=true />` is typically used in production web servers in machine.config you can read more about config values inheritance from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

Answer (score 5):

For those (like me) having troubles with the absence of `AllKeys` property in `IHeaderDictionary` implementation, this is the way I was able to serialize all headers in a string (inside a controller action).

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

// ...

var builder = new StringBuilder(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
{
    builder.AppendLine($"{header.Key}: {header.Value}");
}
var headersDump = builder.ToString();
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

`asp.net core` spits out `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders`
for `Request.Headers.ToString()`, so the solution in that context is:

```
IEnumerable<string> keyValues = context.Request.Headers.Keys.Select(key => key + ": " + string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers[key]));
string requestHeaders = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, keyValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

**.Net 6.0 and above:**

```
public virtual IActionResult Headers()
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new();
    foreach (var header in _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers)
    {
        sb.Append(header.Key);
        sb.Append("=");
        sb.AppendLine(header.Value);
    }
    return Ok(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
string headers = Request.Headers.ToString();
```

But It will return URL encoded string so to decode it use below code,

```
String headers = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Headers.ToString())
```

Comment: For me, it outputs only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders` instead of actual headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all headers as string() in one shot, using this (VB.Net)

```
Request.Headers.ToString.Split(New String() {vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```