# How to loop and write all HTTp Header name/value pairs

Tags: vb.net, http-headers

I am working on a vb.net 2.0 application and trying to read HTTP headers. I am able to get header values through Request.Headers.Get("HTTP_VARIABLE_NAME"). I would like to get all header name/value pairs using Headers property and display on a separate page under a button click event from a given page.

How can I loop and write all name/value pairs please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dump ASP.NET Request headers to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628584/how-to-dump-asp-net-request-headers-to-string)

Comment: Thank you for the info. but that link dosn't show how to write to a page. I want to write the values on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so all credit goes to the poor Microsoft employee who was given the rough task of documenting the system.net namespace. Although I do feel like I could write a better example myself...

> The following code example displays the names and values of all headers in the HTTP request

```
Dim loop1, loop2 As Integer
 Dim arr1(), arr2() As String
 Dim coll As NameValueCollection


' Load Header collection into NameValueCollection object.
coll=Request.Headers

' Put the names of all keys into a string array.
arr1 = coll.AllKeys 
For loop1 = 0 To arr1.GetUpperBound(0)
   Response.Write("Key: " & arr1(loop1) & "<br>")
   arr2 = coll.GetValues(loop1) 
   ' Get all values under this key.
   For loop2 = 0 To arr2.GetUpperBound(0)
      Response.Write("Value " & CStr(loop2) & ": " & Server.HtmlEncode(arr2(loop2)) & "<br>")
    Next loop2
 Next loop1
```

I don't know what you mean by "write to a page", but this should get you started.

Is there a reason that forces you to use .NET 2? .NET 4 is still supported on Windows XP SP3 and up and offers many advantages over previous versions. Just putting it out there.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I mean by write to a page was I want to dislay the output on an .aspx page.